# How to get clear bone broth - without canning

Tags: canning, broth, bones

I like how canning bone broth causes the broth to go clear.

My recipe for bone broth is to cover bones with water and simmer on low for 4-5 hours.   I then strain it several times with the last straining through cheesecloth.  The broth is milky in appearance at this stage.

The left-hand jar was made at the same time as the right hand jar.   I just didn't have room in the canner to do all the jars in 1 batch, so it went in the fridge instead.  After the left-hand was canned, the broth turned clear as well.

Is there a way to get clear bone broth without pressure canning it?  Taste wise, both jars are the same but I find the broth in the right hand jar substantially more appetizing than the left hand jar.

I should point out that when the picture was taken, the broth in both jars was jelled.  They retain the state of milkiness or clarity when heated though.

[image: Bone broth]

Comment: I'd bet that what you are seeing is the solids settling out. Heating (plus stirring, etc.) then agitates the clarified broth and the solids are back in suspension instead of at the bottom of the jar.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I’ve never canned stock. If this has been strained several times why are the hard apparently half full of solids?

Comment: The solids are turkey I added to the jars.   The stock, in this case anyway, is used to become the broth in canned meats.   To each jar was added 100 grams turkey, then the stock was poured in until it reached a 1-1/4" headspace.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to clarify stock of any sort.  The classic method is to use an egg white raft.  First strain your stock, and pass through cheesecloth so that you remove chunks and large particles.  Then make a mixture of two egg whites and a bit of water.  Bring your stock to a boil and stir in the egg white mixture. Remove from boil and let stand for five minutes or so.  Then strain again through cheese cloth.

Comment: I am making stock this week.   I will try this out.   I have never heard of it before.

Comment: @Bookaholic there are plenty of instructions on the web.  "How to clarify stock."